# SEO benefits of HTML5 semantic tags

Tags: seo, html5, semantic-elements

It's widely know that HTML5 offers some elements primarily for semantic purposes. These include: `section`, `article`, `aside`, `header`, `footer`, `nav`, `figure`, `figcaption`, `time`, `mark` & `main`.

Do any of these offer SEO benefits? If so, what are some of the best practices for using these semantic elements?

I've tried to read articles on the subject, but most of the material is non-committal on whether there exist actual SEO benefits of using these tags or not. Almost all WordPress websites (including Instagram.com) use these tags however. I'm sure other platforms do too.

So would love to hear educated opinions from industry experts on how best to use these tags (and which ones are more important than others).

Comment: Doesn't help in the slightest, why would it? visitors don't see your code so therefore why would it help rank?

Comment: Just so that I'm clear, what precisely does it help in then?

Comment: It helps browsers and helps developers code easier and quicker. Search engines will not rank HTML4 websites any better than HTML5 websites with a few exceptions such as responsive design and page speed.